# How to open and analyze Chandrayaan 1 Hysi data?

Tags: software-recommendations, satellite

I have an archive of Chandrayaan 1 Hysi data that contains file formats .lbl, .qub data. What software should i use to visualize and analyze these data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the [ISIS software](https://isis.astrogeology.usgs.gov/Installation/index.html), developed by USGS, to open and analyse those images.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any alternative software that runs on windows platform?

Comment: I think that ENVI also does, but it is not free

Comment: I tried using ENVI. But it doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried this ? http://sbn.psi.edu/archive/dawn/vir/certified/DWNVVIR_V1A/DOCUMENT/ENVI_TUTORIAL/DAWNVIR_ENVI_TUTORIAL_V3.PDF